# AngularJS - Change controller by condition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple form  with data which summarize the pressed items ( via addition)

(**[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/IfEfaWIJ/3/edit)**)

[image]

(700=300+400)

The form is bounded with `ng-controller="OrderFormController"`

Which inturn has this method :

```
$scope.total = function(){

        var total = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.services, function(s){
            if (s.active){
                total+= s.price;
            }
        });

        return total;
    };
```

All ok.

But look at the top if the picture , there is a check box.

When it's checked , I want to do **totally different calculation** inside `$scope.total`

Let's say , instead of *addition*  - do *multiplication* :

```
$scope.total = function(){

        var total = 1;
        angular.forEach($scope.services, function(s){
            if (s.active){
                total*= s.price;
            }
        });

        return total;
    };
```

*Of course I could check inside the method whether  the checkbox is checked , but I don't want to do that.*

**Question**

What is the *right* way ( i'm angularjs beginner) of bounding it to a different method   (according to `checked`/`unchecked`)?

Comment: _"Of course I could check inside the method itself if the checkbox is checked , but I dont want to do that."_ - Explain your reasons.

Comment: @Stewie in real world it could be 1000 lines of code which does different things. there is a special controller for this. how do I bound it to a different controller based on a condition ( my main question actually)

Comment: @RoyiNamir I would consider using a service for sharing that information then.

Comment: The strategy pattern springs to mind. Like Lasse said it sounds as if you would be better off with a service, or a set of services, that do the calcs. There shouldn't really be 1000s of lines of code in a controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a built-in way to choose a controller based on some condition. The `ngController` directive doesn't seem to play well with interpolation of the name via `{{ }}`, or passing a string version of the controller name, so it doesn't seem to be possible to choose a controller by `ngController` dynamically based on some condition in the scope.

The most flexible solution to this I think is writing a custom directive, that accepts a string variable (including one returned by an expression)

```
<div dynamic-controller="checked ? 'CheckedController' : 'UncheckedController'">
  Inside {{name}}  
</div>
```

That then takes the name of the controller, puts it in an `ng-controller` attribute, and then (re)compiles the element, and do this whenever the expression returned by `dynamic-controller` changes. This could be done as follows:

```
app.directive('dynamicController', function($compile) {
  return  {
    transclude: 'element',
    scope: {
      'dynamicController': '=' 
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
      var el = null;
      scope.$watch('dynamicController',function() {
        if (el) {
          el.remove();
          el = null;
        }
        transclude(function(clone) {
          clone.attr('ng-controller', scope.dynamicController);
          clone.removeAttr('dynamic-controller');
          el = $compile(clone[0])(scope.$parent)
          element.after(el);
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

You can see this in action [in this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E0FlpUngLTwUgEa6Zf3u?p=preview)

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to choose controller, but keep the template the same, is to have the template in an external file, and wrap it in an `ngIf`, so:

```
<div ng-if="checked" ng-controller="CheckedController" ng-include="'template.html'">
</div>
<div ng-if="!checked" ng-controller="UncheckedController" ng-include="'template.html'">
</div>
```

As can be seen [in this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4PI12ve0aeQSHznMvG96?p=preview)

Comment: And how will `checked` will be evaluated (i'm new to angular) ?

Comment: `checked` is a boolean variable on the scope. It can be controlled by a checkbox using `ngModel` like `<input ng-model="checked" type="checkbox" />`. The [linked Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4PI12ve0aeQSHznMvG96?p=preview) uses this. You could instead call some function on the scope, that returns a boolean variable. You could do something similar with ngSwitch to use strings instead of a boolean if you prefer (or have more than 2 controllers to choose between).

Answer (score 3):

Just delegate to different methods based on if the box is checked

```
$scope.total = function() {
  if($scope.isMultiply) {
    // your multiply code
  } else {
    // non-multiply code
  }
}
```

You don't want to check to see if the checkbox is checked, but there's no way around that. Some code somewhere is going to have to respond to the state of the checkbox. This is simple, straightforward, and easy to read.

Comment: As I said , for simplicity it's a multiplication instead of addition , but in real world it could be 1000 lines of code which does different things. there is a special controller for this. how do I bound it to a different controller based on a condition ( my main question actually).

Comment: you don't. wrap up the different condition in a service and delegate to that. as i said, there's no way around having to use a conditional to decide what to do when there is state involved.

Comment: p.s. how can I  write `$scope.isMultiply` if the checkbox is outside on ng scope ?

Comment: put it in the scope then